# Exercise $14$, section $2.C$ - Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

**Exercise.** Suppose $U_1,. . .,U_m$ are finite-dimensional subspaces of $V$. Prove that
$U_1+. . .+U_m$ is finite-dimensional and $\dim (U_1+. . .+U_m) \le \dim U_1+. . .+\dim U_m$.

---

The following is my attempt at a proof.

**Proof**: Let $B_1,. . .,B_m$ be bases of the respective subspaces $U_1,. . .,U_m$. Then, $B_1,. . .,B_m$ spans $U_1+. . .+U_m$ showing that $U_1+. . .+U_m$ is finite-dimensional.

To prove the second part, note that the length of a linearly independent list is less than or equal to the length of a spanning list. Thus, we split it into two cases:

1. Suppose that $B_1,. . .,B_m$ is linearly independent. Then, $$\dim (U_1+. . .+U_m) = \dim U_1+. . .+\dim U_m.$$
2. Suppose that $B_1,. . .,B_m$ is not linearly independent. Thus, we can reduce this spanning list to a basis of $U_1+. . .+U_m$. In which case we have that $$\dim (U_1+. . .+U_m) < \dim U_1+. . .+\dim U_m.$$

which show that $\dim (U_1+. . .+U_m) \le \dim U_1+. . .+\dim U_m$.

---

Is the proof above correct?

I used a theorem proved earlier that a spanning list in a vector space can be reduced to a basis of that vector space.

Answer (score 3):

This proof is correct, but your case 1 can be omitted. You merely need to note that $B_1,...,B_m$ spans the vector space, thus can be reduced to a basis for it. The split into case 1 and case 2 is already covered in the proof of the theorem you mention at the bottom of your question, which I'm sure included that the length of the basis was less than or equal to the length of the spanning list.

Incidentally, looking at a PDF of the textbook, it looks like you could have proved this slightly more easily by using the result 2.43 in that book.

[image: screenshot of textbook in question, section 2.43]

Use induction, that is show that $\dim(U_1+...+U_n)+\dim U_{n+1}\leq \dim(U_1+...+U_{n+1})$.

Comment: Do you mean by splitting $U_1+. . .+U_m$ into the sum of two subspaces $U+W$. Where we get $U$ by adding a few subspaces and get $W$ by adding the left over subspaces. Then using the formula for the sum of two subspaces?

Comment: @Seeker Use induction. I'll add something to the answer.

Comment: Oh yeah that works as well and much shorter. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Actually as I was trying induction, I got stuck at one part. Attempt: Cleary $\dim (U_1)\le \dim(U_1)$. Suppose inductively that $\dim (U_1+. . .+U_n)\le \dim U_1+. . .+\dim U_n$. We need to show that $\dim (U_1+. . .+U_n+U_{n+1}) \le \dim U_1 + . . .\dim U_n + \dim U_{n+1}$. But I don't see how we could do that. As we can using the induction hypothesis, add $\dim (U_{n+1})$ to both sides. But then we get $\dim (U_1+. . .+U_n)+\dim U_{n+1}\le \dim U_1+. . .+\dim U_n + \dim U_{n+1}$. Whereas we need to show $\dim (U_1+. . .+U_n+U_{n+1})\le \dim U_1 + . . .+\dim U_{n+1}$.

Comment: No you don't need to do all that, the induction does all of the work except for the last case. You might want to ask another question about it.

Comment: @Seeker To prove what you want to conclude, it would be enough to prove that $\dim(U_1+\cdots+U_{n+1})\leq \dim(U_1+\cdots U_n)+\dim U_{n+1}$. Now, why is that true?

Comment: @Seeker Given what's on the book, can you prove the case $n=2$?

Comment: @Seeker At a guess you're a bit shaky about mathematical induction, leo is hinting about it.

Comment: Please can you not ask followup questions in comments? Nobody else but me can answer. Could you just ask another question? Thanks.